# Is this metric on the space of $\mu$-measurable functions complete?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, measurable-functions

Below we use [Bochner measurability](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_measurable_function) and [Bochner integral](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bochner_integral). Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a *complete finite* measure space,
- $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space,
- $S (X)$ the space of $\mu$-simple functions from $X$ to $E$, and
- $L^0 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-measurable functions from $X$ to $E$.
- $L^1 (X)$ the space of $\mu$-integrable functions from $X$ to $E$.

For simplicity, we write
$$
\mu (|f - g| > \delta) := \mu (\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\})
\quad \forall \delta >0.
$$

Notice that the completeness of $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ implies $\{x \in X : |f (x) - g(x)| > \delta\} \in \mathcal A$. We define
$$
\hat \rho (f, g) := \inf_{\delta >0} \{ \mu (|f - g| > \delta)  +\delta \}
\quad \forall f, g \in L^0 (X).
$$

Then $\hat \rho$ is a pseudometric on $L^0(X)$. Also, $\hat \rho (f_n, f) \to 0$ IFF $f_n \to f$ [in measure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Convergence_in_measure#Definitions), i.e.,
$$
\mu (\{x \in X : |f_n (x)-f(x)| > \varepsilon\}) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0
\quad \forall \varepsilon>0,
$$

> Could you elaborate on the completeness of $(L^0 (X), \hat \rho)$?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: At https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/ seach for "Cauchy in measure" (with quotation marks) to find some related discussions.  Also: what is $\mu$-measurable for $E$-valued function when $E$ is not separable?  Bochner measurable?

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yess, I use Bochner measurability. Have you sent me the wrong link? It's *"How to ask a good question"*.

Comment: Sorry, just try https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/789823/96609).

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you so much for your indication! I'm happy that the answer is affirmative.